# PHP sort json Array by user defined order

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have bellow array im trying sort

```
Array
(
  [amendment] => 1
  [lcnumber] => A1114564564CT
  [31D] => New Note
  [27] => 0/0 (Number)(Total)
  [31C] => 
  [42C] => 
)
Array
(
[amendment] => 2
[lcnumber] => A1114564564CT
[31D] => IN SINGAPORE (120 Days from L/C issue date)
[42C] => 20 Days from B/L Date - Sight
[27] => 2/2 (Number)(Total)
[31C] => Exceeding
)
```

my expected out put is

```
    Array
(
  [amendment] => 1
  [lcnumber] => A1114564564CT
  [31D] => New Note
  [27] => 0/0 (Number)(Total)
  [31C] => 
  [42C] => 
)
Array
(
[amendment] => 2
[lcnumber] => A1114564564CT
[31D] => IN SINGAPORE (120 Days from L/C issue date)
[27] => 2/2 (Number)(Total)
[31C] => Exceeding
[42C] => 20 Days from B/L Date - Sight
```

)

means i will have pre defined key order of ('amendment','lcnumber','31D','27','31C','42C')

i tried using usort but i was not able to move forward.

```
usort($myarray, '');
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from? One way to ensure keys are the correct order is to create an empty array with the keys first, then populate them.

Comment: @JacobMulquin data coming from third party application. so it is not in order. im trying to make my own sorting order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is build a new array with the keys already in the correct order:

```
$correct_order = ['amendment', 'lcnumber', '31D', '27', '31C', '42C'];

$records = [
    [
        'amendment' => 1,
        'lcnumber' => 'A1114564564CT',
        '31D' => 'New Note',
        '27' => '0/0 (Number)(Total)',
        '31C' => '',
        '42C' => ''
    ],
    [
        'amendment' => 2,
        'lcnumber' => 'A1114564564CT',
        '31D' => 'IN SINGAPORE (120 Days from L/C issue date)',
        '27' => '2/2 (Number)(Total)',
        '42C' => '20 Days from B/L Date - Sight',
        '31C' => 'Exceeding'
    ],
    [
        '42C' => '0 Days from B/L Date - Sight',
        'amendment' => 3,
        '31D' => 'IN SINGAPORE (90 Days from L/C issue date)',
        'lcnumber' => 'A1114564564CT',
        '31C' => 'Exceeding',
        '27' => '3/3 (Number)(Total)'
    ],
];

$corrected = [];
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $new = array_fill_keys($correct_order, []);
    foreach ($new as $key => &$val) {
        $val = $record[$key];
    }
    $corrected[] = $new;
}
unset($val);

var_dump($corrected);
```

Results in

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["amendment"]=>
    int(1)
    ["lcnumber"]=>
    string(13) "A1114564564CT"
    ["31D"]=>
    string(8) "New Note"
    [27]=>
    string(19) "0/0 (Number)(Total)"
    ["31C"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["42C"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["amendment"]=>
    int(2)
    ["lcnumber"]=>
    string(13) "A1114564564CT"
    ["31D"]=>
    string(43) "IN SINGAPORE (120 Days from L/C issue date)"
    [27]=>
    string(19) "2/2 (Number)(Total)"
    ["31C"]=>
    string(9) "Exceeding"
    ["42C"]=>
    string(29) "20 Days from B/L Date - Sight"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    ["amendment"]=>
    int(3)
    ["lcnumber"]=>
    string(13) "A1114564564CT"
    ["31D"]=>
    string(42) "IN SINGAPORE (90 Days from L/C issue date)"
    [27]=>
    string(19) "3/3 (Number)(Total)"
    ["31C"]=>
    string(9) "Exceeding"
    ["42C"]=>
    string(28) "0 Days from B/L Date - Sight"
  }
}
```